# MongoDB inserts float when trying to insert integer

Tags: mongodb

```
   > db.data.update({'name': 'zero'}, {'$set': {'value': 0}}) 
   > db.data.findOne({'name': 'zero})
    {'name': 'zero', 'value': 0.0}
```

How do I get Mongo to insert an integer?

Thank you

Comment: which version of mongodb do you use ?

Comment: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-854

Comment: note that in my case , when i wanted to {$set:{val:NumberInt(0)}} at some "val" that's already set as Long , it didn't change it. I had to first change it to some other value , then change it back to 0 , for the NumberInt(0) to take effect

Comment: I had same problem, after realizing I had mistakenly changed an int32 to double, setting it back using NumberInt() did not fix the type unless I first changed to a different value.

Answer (score 431, accepted):

```
db.data.update({'name': 'zero'}, {'$set': {'value': NumberInt(0)}})
```

You can also use NumberLong.

Comment: but in findOne it says NumberLong(0) not as 0

Comment: By default, the mongo shell treats all numbers as floating-point values. So we need to explicitly specify what type of number we want to use e.g. NumberInt or NumberLong.  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/shell-types/

Comment: I have a question. The NumberInt is only provided in mongo shell, how do you do that in JavaScript language like node.js?

Comment: @Shawyeok here is an answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21870772/3815843

Comment: It is important to take into account that ints have bounds. If the number is big consider using NumberLong

Comment: @GRiMe2D that covers `long`, but not `int`.  ~Strangely, I can only find a `Long` type in the Node.js driver...~ oddly, the 32-bit integer type is called `Int32` in the docs (why didn't they call `Long` `Int64` instead?)

Answer (score 25):

A slightly simpler syntax (in Robomongo at least) worked for me:

```
db.database.save({ Year : NumberInt(2015) });
```

Comment: here is my code `getRawPhoneNumber(phoneNumber: string) {
    let phNumber = phoneNumber.replace(/[^0-9+]/g, '');
    return NumberInt(phNumber);
  }` it  says  **cannot find `NumberInt`**

Answer (score 7):

If the value type is already double, then update the value with $set command can not change the value type double to int when using NumberInt() or NumberLong() function.
So, to Change the value type, it must update the whole record.

```
var re = db.data.find({"name": "zero"})
re['value']=NumberInt(0)
db.data.update({"name": "zero"}, re)
```

Comment: `$set` worked at least in Mongo 4.2, so perhaps this was a bug.

Answer (score -15):

Well, it's JavaScript, so what you have in 'value' is a Number, which can be an integer or a float. But there's not really a difference in JavaScript. From [Learning JavaScript](http://oreilly.com/javascript/excerpts/learning-javascript/javascript-datatypes-variables.html):

> **The Number Data Type**
>
> Number data types in JavaScript are floating-point numbers, but they may or may not have a fractional component. If they don’t have a decimal point or fractional component, they’re treated as integers—base-10 whole numbers in a range of –2<sup>53</sup> to 2<sup>53</sup>.

Comment: Actually that is not true. While JS does not see a difference, as soon as you connect to mongo from another language (e.g. java) you will very much feel the difference.

Comment: My application has broken in different points only for one reason, int is saved and returned as float. I suspect the cause must be some manual insertions I did via mongo shell which uses javascript.