# How to insert the timestamp in milliseconds as NumberLong in MongoDB using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I new to nodejs and trying implement mongodb insert of current timestamp as milliseconds using nodejs its getting inserted as double value. Can anyone help me how to insert this as NumberLong value.

```
var data = {
        myId : uniqueId,
        Timestamp : Date.now(),   ---> This one is getting inserted as double.
        userData : applicationData
      }
    }
```

I also try to insert like this but its getting insert as String.

```
 var mongo=require('mongodb');
 var Long = mongo.Long;

 var data = {
        myId : uniqueId,
        Timestamp : Long.fromString((Date.now() + "")), ---> This one is getting inserted as String.
        userData : applicationData
      }
    }
```

Comment: what is `NumberLong ` value? can you give an example?

Comment: From mongoDb Shell if query the data Long value will represented like NumberLong in mongo.
For Ex : The above value should get inserted like below in Mongo DB

     {
          "_id" : ObjectId("58832821e8f07b1a235ae273"),
          "myId" : "AB223",
          "Timestamp" : NumberLong(1484990497160),
           "userData" : {.....}
     }

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21870772/2965883

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because JavaScript Numbers are Always 64-bit Floating Point. 
You can use Mongo driver's Long ( https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/long.html ) to get rid of this problem.

```
var Long = require('mongodb').Long;
var current_millies = new Date().getTime();

var data = {
 myId : uniqueId,
 timestamp : Long.fromNumber(current_millies),
 userData : applicationData
}
```