# MongoDB: Force datatype of fields?

Tags: mongodb

This is a follow-up question to [MongoDB: class java.lang.Double cannot be cast to class java.lang.Long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65141475/mongodb-class-java-lang-double-cannot-be-cast-to-class-java-lang-long)

> The problem probably is that any of the indicated fields is actually stored as Double instead of Long.

Is there a way that I can force a datatype for some fields in MongoDB?

I want the insert of a document to fail, if the datatype does not match.

Comment: Hi @guetti. Sorry for the late reply. I realized your comment, but in fact D.SM provided you, in my opinion, the best possible answer. In any case, if you identified the cause of the original problem, please, try it, just to make sure that it works properly for that concrete use case. Also, use the different conversion functions provided by the Mongo Shell and the different Mongo libraries to make sure that the information is written in the right format. If you consider that I can be of any help, please, do not hesitate to contact me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use schema validation as explained in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/