# How to store Azure Service Bus Message ids of package-internal type 'Long' in mongodb?

Tags: typescript, mongodb, azureservicebus

I'm using Azure Service Bus (@azure/service-bus) in a TypeScript-based nest.js service to schedule messages to be delivered at a future point in time. I need to be able to cancel those messages before the delivery date if needed. My plan was to create messages and schedule them for a delivery date using the `scheduleMessages` function, which returns an ID of the scheduled message. I would then save the message ID into my mongodb database, so that later on I can pull that back out and use it to cancel the message with the `cancelScheduledMessages` function which takes that id as a parameter.

However, it seems that the @azure/service-bus package uses it's own internal `Long` type for these ids. This type is not exported from the package, so if I convert ids from this `Long` type to any other type (as I need to in order to store them in my mongo database), I am unable to convert back.

The documentation for the `scheduleMessages` function has this to say about the ids:

> Save the Long type as-is in your application without converting to number. Since JavaScript only supports 53 bit numbers, converting the Long to number will cause loss in precision

Surely there has to be a way for me to save these to a database and use them later? Or does *"Save the Long type as-is in your application"* mean that I'm just out of luck here? I find it hard to believe that the fine folks making this service bus package would not allow us any flexibility with saving an id like this.

I appreciate any and all suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var Long = require('mongodb').Long;

const uri = 'mongodb://testuser:mysecret@localhost:27017,localhost:27018,localhost:27019/?replicaSet=replSet';


var document = {'longInteger': Long.fromString("123") };

var dbName = "mydb";
var collectionName = "mycollection";

const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useUnifiedTopology: true });

var db = client.db(dbName);
var collection = db.collection(collectionName);

var document = {'someLongValue' : Long.fromString("123")};

collection.insertOne(document, function (err, result) {});
```

See similar post [Node js Mongodb Query NumberLong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21870044/node-js-mongodb-query-numberlong)

Comment: Thanks for the response! This doesn't quite work, as the Long type defined by the service-bus package isn't compatible with this Long declaration from Mongo. I ended up using a third party package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-long) to add support to mongo for the types of Longs I am using.

Comment: The @azure/service-bus and @azure/event-hubs packages depend on the "long" NPM package for the "Long" datatype.  Please check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/long for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The Mongo Long type is not compatible with @azure/service-bus, but after looking in the source files of the plugin, I found this comment at the bottom of the Long type definition:

`` export = Long; // compatible with `import Long from "long" ``

With this, I was able to use this compatible type instead, and save to mongo using the mongoose-long npm package which adds support for the Long type compatible with Long from 'long'.