# MongoDB - update a property with incremental values

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection called dealers as follows.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b9ba196cd5f5af83bb0dc71"),
    "name" : "SOME COMPANY",
    "outletID" : "GS0061920",
    "companyID" : "GC0050397"
}
```

I have about 5000 documents in this collection where `outletID` and `companyID` properties are empty.

**I would like to update both of these properties for all documents in this collection with incremental values.**

I'm not sure how I should go about this.

Note: MongoDB 3.4 is in use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are running on mongodb shell. You can use the following:

```
> var counter = 1;
> db.collection.find().forEach(
      function(elem) { 
        db.myColl.update(
          { "outletID" : null, "companyID" : null}, 
          {$set:{ outletID: counter , companyID: counter } 
          }); 
       counter++;
     });
```

The mongo shell is an interactive JavaScript interface. I have used JS for the task. counter is a simple variable which is used to update values. **$set** is used to update the fields.

> The $set operator replaces the value of a field with the specified value. You can find more data in its [official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/index.html).

I created a sample data and tested my function. Hope it works fine.
[image: Image showing the commands I ran in shell]

Comment: You can update the queries as you want. I considered null in place of "". @HadidAli, you can update queries accordingly. Hope you got the methodology I want to convey.

Comment: Thanks that works but there's glitch. Both properties are updated with a decimal point at the end. How can I resolve this issue? "outletID" : 32000.0, "companyID" : 51000.0

Comment: There shouldn't be. You can see my output. can You share your script.

Comment: var val_outletID = 32;
var val_companyID = 51;
db.dealers.find().forEach(
   function(elem) { 
      db.dealers.update(
         { "outletID" : null, "companyID" : null}, 
            {$set:{ outletID: val_outletID , companyID: val_companyID }
      }); 
      val_outletID++;
   val_companyID++;
});

Comment: Hey @HadidAli can you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218484/mongodb-inserts-float-when-trying-to-insert-integer